# EF Code First Migration: How to inherit MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to derive a class from MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion in my project.

```
public abstract class BaseDatabaseInitializer<TContext> : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, MigrationConfiguration>
    where TContext : DbContext
```

MigrationConfiguration class looks like this

```
internal sealed class MigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<QAdminDbContext>
{
    public MigrationConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(QAdminDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

But I am not allowed to do so and am getting an error

```
"Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext,Lutron.Application.QAdmin.Database.EntityConfiguration.MigrationConfiguration>' is less accessible than class 'Lutron.Application.QAdmin.Database.BaseDatabaseInitializer<TContext>'    E:\Proj\Lutron\Code\src\Lutron\Gulliver\QAdmin\DataAccess\Database\BaseDatabaseInitializer.cs   17  27  Database"
```

This is due to the fact that MigrateDatabaseToLatestVerion class has explicitly defined where clause for MigrationConfigurationContext.

Since, in my custom class, I have explicitly defined '`Configuration`' class, I can't add where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the abstract initializer class is a public class, but the migrations class is internal. Change them both to public classes or both to internal classes, but then there is another issue.

The C# compiler will see that someone is allowed to try `BaseDatabaseInitializer<SomeOtherContext>`, but the MigrationConfiguration class isn't convertible to a migration with a type parameter of SomeOtherContext, so it won't allow the code to compile.

There are some possible solutions, but I think it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want more control over how and when the migrations execute I'd probably take a different approach and implement IDatabaseInitializer, which still allows you to plug the class into the application as a database initializer, something like:

```
public abstract class BaseDatabaseInitializer<TContext> : 
    IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> _migrations;

    protected BaseDatabaseInitializer(DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> migrations)
    {
        _migrations = migrations;
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        new DbMigrator(_migrations).Update();
    }
}
```